# Set response headers from HTMLRewriter in Cloudflare Workers

Tags: javascript, service-worker, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I'm using [HTMLRewriter](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/runtime-apis/html-rewriter/) to find images to preload. Is there any way to inject them as a "Link" response header using service workers?

```js
addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  event.passThroughOnException()
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

class ElementHandler {
  element(element) {
    console.log(`Incoming image: ${element.getAttribute('src')}`)
    // Add this image to response header (as link)
  }
}

async function handleRequest(req) {
  const res = await fetch(req)

  return new HTMLRewriter().on('img[loading=eager]', new ElementHandler()).transform(res)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a fundamental problem here: `HTMLRewriter` is designed to rewrite HTML as it streams through, so that you do not have to load the entire document into memory at once. But if the content is streaming through, then that implies that the response headers must have already been sent to the client, since HTTP does not allow streaming content until after the response headers. (Technically HTTP supports something called "trailers", but they wouldn't help here.)

In order to populate headers based on data parsed using `HTMLRewriter`, you would have to buffer the entire HTML into memory. This is generally undesirable:

- It'll make your Worker more likely to hit memory limits and fail.
- It means you need to fetch the entire response from the origin before any of it can be sent to the client, which increases latency. **This may actually defeat the purpose of your preloading optimization.** When HTML streams to the browser, the browser can begin loading each image as soon as it sees the `<img>` tag. Preload headers will only help if they can be delivered sooner than the HTML content. But if your worker has to read the HTML content anyway to find these tags, and delivery of content to the client is delayed in the meantime, the latency may be overall worse.

With all that said, here's what the code would look like to read the content into memory:

```js
class ElementHandler {
  constructor() {
    this.links = [];
  }
  element(element) {
    // Remember the link off to the side.
    this.links.push(element.getAttribute('src'));
  }
  addHeadersTo(res) {
    // ... add this.links to res.headers here ...
  }
}

async function handleRequest(req) {
  const res = await fetch(req);

  let handler = new ElementHandler();

  let res2 = new HTMLRewriter()
    .on('img[loading=eager]', handler).transform(res);

  // Force entire HTML to be read into memory.
  // THIS IS INEFFICIENT!
  let data = await res2.arrayBuffer();

  // Make a THIRD response based on the buffered data
  // that we consumed from res2.
  let res3 = new Response(data, res2);

  // Modify its headers based on the links.
  handler.addHeadersTo(res3);

  // Now we can return that.
  return res3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation! I'll stick with sending link headers from origin.

Comment: if all I am doing is adding something before </head>, can I just use body.replace('</head>', 'xxx</head>') and bypass HTMLRewriter altogether? I also have to set server cookies

Comment: @Tallboy To do `body.replace()` you would first need to load the entire body into memory as a string, which implies the same problems described above. This is a case where HTMLRewriter would serve you much better -- you can use it to insert HTML at the end of `<head>` in a streaming way, without loading the entire document into memory upfront.